# Re-Parsing JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a tweet data which I need to parse:

```
"{u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'', u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 325495490122772480L, u'favorite_count': 0, u'source': u'<a href=""http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imdb-movies-tv/id342792525?mt=8&uo=4"" rel=""nofollow"">IMDb Movies & TV on iOS</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': None, u'entities': {u'symbols': [], u'user_mentions': [{u'indices': [56, 68], u'id_str': u'244186942', u'screen_name': u'ploughman71', u'name': u'Paul Hughes', u'id': 244186942}], u'hashtags': [{u'indices': [50, 55], u'text': u'IMDb'}], u'urls': [{u'url': u'...', u'indices': [27, 49], u'expanded_url': u'...', u'display_url': u'imdb.com/title/tt0068646'}]}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, u'id_str': u'325495490122772480', u'retweet_count': 0, u'in_reply_to_user_id': None, u'favorited': False, u'user': {u'follow_request_sent': False, u'profile_use_background_image': True, u'contributors_enabled': False, u'id': 171859103, u'verified': False, u'profile_text_color': u'333333', u'profile_image_url_https': u'...', u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'DDEEF6', u'entities': {u'description': {u'urls': []}}, u'followers_count': 190, u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'C0DEED', u'location': u'pengwern ', u'default_profile_image': False, u'id_str': u'171859103', u'is_translation_enabled': False, u'utc_offset': None, u'statuses_count': 5107, u'description': u""My soul you have coz i dont mean shit i'd sell to the devil for another hit"", u'friends_count': 1163, u'profile_link_color': u'0084B4', u'profile_image_url': u'...', u'notifications': False, u'geo_enabled': True, u'profile_background_color': u'C0DEED', u'profile_banner_url': u'...', u'profile_background_image_url': u'...', u'screen_name': u'jay_me7', u'lang': u'en', u'following': False, u'profile_background_tile': False, u'favourites_count': 104, u'name': u'Jamie David Williams', u'url': None, u'created_at': u'Wed Jul 28 10:13:24 +0000 2010', u'profile_background_image_url_https': u'...', u'time_zone': None, u'protected': False, u'default_profile': True, u'is_translator': False, u'listed_count': 2}, u'geo': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, u'possibly_sensitive': False, u'lang': u'en', u'created_at': u'Sat Apr 20 06:25:46 +0000 2013', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': None}"
```

When I search for json_obj['time_zone'] it gives me error that this key doesn't exist where it clearly is there, but the catch is it's within the 'user' entity which gets hidden at the first layer. I am not sure how I can extract the "time_zone" key from the above string?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you posted is the repr of a Python dict and not JSON. You also need to post the *exact* error you get, not a self-written description of it.

Comment: So... you are asking how to access dictionaries in Python?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this:

```
json_obj['user']['time_zone']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tested it and it worked. I mistakenly did this: json_obj_user = json.loads(json_obj['user']) to then get json_obj_user['time_zone'] and it gave me json parsing error. didn't know I could use nested []'s to get the nested objects out.